# Sorting data into categories and showing category headlines

Tags: sorting, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

In AngularJS, for the given *dataset of animals*, what is the best way to produce both the *personality view* and the *size view*?

---

**Personality view**

```
Animals by personality:
Cute
    Cat
    Dog
Scary
    Snake
    Shark
```

---

**Size view**

```
Animals by size:
Small
    Cat
Medium
    Dog
    Snake
Large
    Shark
```

---

**Dataset**

```
$scope.animals = [
    { 
        name: 'Cat',
        pers: 'cute',
        size: 'small'
    },
    { 
        name: 'Dog',
        pers: 'cute',
        size: 'medium'
    },
    { 
        name: 'Snake',
        pers: 'scary',
        size: 'medium'
    },
    { 
        name: 'Shark',
        pers: 'scary',
        size: 'large'
    }
];
```

---

**What I currently do**

For the personality view, I currently use the following code:

```
<h1>Animals by personality</h1>

<h2>Cute</h2>
<li ng-repeat="animal in animals | filter: 'cute'">
    {{ animal.name }}
</li>

<h2>Scary</h2>
<li ng-repeat="animal in animals | filter: 'scary'">
    {{ animal.name }}
</li>
```

And then for the size view, I copy the above code and change the h1, h2s and filters.

The whole point here is: Sort the dataset by category, but display the category headline for each category.

*So my question is, this very much seams like a known problem? How to best solve it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) filter has nothing to do here. What you want to do is not to filter, since you want to display all the data, but to order, and the [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) filter is the way to do that.

However, there is no "built-in" way to also display the title. You can make something like [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMpX/), but it would clearly be a best idea to create your own directive.

```
<h1>Animals by personality</h1>

<li ng-repeat="animal in animals | orderBy: pers">
    <h2 ng-show="isNewPersonality(animal)">{{ animal.pers }}</h2>
    {{ animal.name }}
</li>
```

*Controller* :

```
$scope.lastPersonality = null;
$scope.isNewPersonality = function (animal)
{
    if ($scope.lastPersonality != animal.pers)
    {
        $scope.lastPersonality = animal.pers;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Now what if an animal has two personalities, say a cat that is both `cute` and `scary`? What your code does is it creates a new group `cute and scary` and puts the cat in there. However, I would like the cat to show up in both the `cute` and the `scary` group, instead of creating an entirely new group for it. http://jsfiddle.net/5DMpX/3/

Comment: Well, that's much more complicate to do. What I would do is, in my own directive of course, to create a 2D array from the initial dataset. The first dimension memorizes the title (cute, scary, …), the second the data. It's pretty simple to do in the link function, for instance. Now, for the display, I would simply use two nested ng-repeat :) .

Answer (score 0):

Use two nested ng-repeats. You can either fetch the categories separately, or extract them from the animals array using underscorejs.

Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in personalities" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
    <h2>{{p}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="a in animals" ng-show="a.pers == p">{{a.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.animals = [...]
$scope.personalities = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.animals, 'pers'));
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3811/